# Flutter menuBar: how to remove background/border?

Tags: flutter, menubar

Flutter menuBar: how to remove background/border?

```
MenuBar(children: [
   MenuItemButton(child: Text('Login')),
   MenuItemButton(child: Text('Register')),
])

--------------------
| Login  Register  |
--------------------
```

How to remove background (to be transparent) and border?

```
Login  Register
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `style` property and `MenuStyle` class (https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/MenuStyle-class.html):

`elevation` should be set to `0` (otherwise, with a `Color.transparent`, you'll see the widget's shadow).

```dart
MenuBar(
  style: MenuStyle(
    backgroundColor: MaterialStatePropertyAll<Color>(Colors.transparent),
    elevation: MaterialStatePropertyAll<double>(0),
    shape: MaterialStatePropertyAll<ContinuousRectangleBorder>(ContinuousRectangleBorder())
  ),
  children: ...,
)
```

Here's a full example. Changing `backgroundColor` property of `Scaffold` will demonstrate that `MenuBar` is effectively transparent, shadowless and with rectangular borders:

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const MaterialApp(
      title: 'MenuBar Demo',
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor: Colors.red,
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: [
            Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
              children: <Widget>[
                Expanded(
                  child: MenuBar(
                      style: const MenuStyle(
                          backgroundColor: MaterialStatePropertyAll<Color>(
                              Colors.transparent),
                          elevation: MaterialStatePropertyAll<double>(0),
                          shape: MaterialStatePropertyAll<
                              ContinuousRectangleBorder>(
                              ContinuousRectangleBorder())),
                      children: [
                        SubmenuButton(menuChildren: [
                          MenuItemButton(
                              onPressed: () {},
                              child: const MenuAcceleratorLabel('Test'))
                        ], child: const MenuAcceleratorLabel('File'))
                      ]),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Tried the backgroundColor. It becomes darker, not transparent. Could you also add shape for non-border? Thanks

Comment: @eastwater you see it darker because of the `elevation`, setting a transparent background will leave only the widget's drop shadow. I've updated my answer, let me know if it's clearer now

Comment: Added the elevation and shape, did not work. It still has background, elevation and border. thanks.

Comment: @eastwater i confirm that my code works, i've added a full example in my answer. You can test it by changing the Scaffold's `backgroundColor` property. Doing this, you'll see that MenuBar is transparent. Probably you're missing something in your original code.